# Unable to build project due to manifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, android-manifest

I am creating an app for uni and when I build my project I am receiving an error from my build manifest. This is the error I am getting. Would anyone know how to fix this? I have looked at similar questions and have tried everything
Thanks
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<meta-data android:name="com.example.b00683207.meditracker.Actforfragmentname"></meta-data>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".CreateLine" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <activity android:name=".Actforfragment"></activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: share manifest code

Comment: just added build manifest

Comment: This is a typo; you close the activity tag before the intent filter starts

Answer (score 2):

You have closed the activity tag before defining the intent-filters. 
It should be like:

```
<activity>
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Your code still looks the same as before. Have you made the change? You need to add </activity> on line 29 and replace "/>" with ">" on line 22 (referencing your screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this description](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element) of the `intent-filter` element, you can see that it's supposed to appear only inside `activity`, `activity-alias`, `service`, or `receiver` elements. Your manifest has an intent-filter that is nested inside some other element -- you need to move it.

Answer (score 0):

you closed CreateLine activity tag

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: its making no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".CreateLine">

          <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Actforfragment"></activity>
```

Please once have a look at closing < /activity> near < CreateLine> as you are trying to close it earlier it is showing as an error.
You are closing activity and keeping intent filters later where that should be **enclosed between activity tag**

Comment: it made no difference

Answer (score -1):

Can you post your manifest? I'm not sure why it would fail on an intent-filter as these are common to use for choosing the activity that the application launches or for other purposes.

Here's an example of one that works in Android studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.audioauthority.www.zodiac2019">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.audioauthority.www.zodiac2019.openMain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".SecurityActivity"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <receiver
                android:name=".AutoStart"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```